# Python asyncio blocks on coroutine, but not websockets

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Consider the following code:

```
async def remote_data_retriever():
    remote = Remote(sock_path)
    while True:
        Cached.update_global(remote.get_global())
        await asyncio.sleep(RTR_RETR_INTERVAL)


async def on_message(websocket, path):
    async for message in websocket:
        data = Cached.get_global()
        await websocket.send(json.dumps(data.__dict__))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    ssl_context.load_cert_chain(RTR_CERT_PATH)
    app_server = websockets.serve(on_message, RTR_LISTEN_HOST, RTR_LISTEN_PORT, ssl=ssl_context)
    try:
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(app_server)
        print('1')
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(remote_data_retriever())
        print('2')
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This code will print '1' and then never print '2'. How to correctly schedule a coroutine so it does NOT block on the following call

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(remote_data_retriever())
```

?

Comment: you use loop `while True` which never ends - why did you expect to exit this loop? `run_until_complete(remote_data_retriever())` is running till you exit this loop.

Comment: as for me you should ratehr use [create_task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) to add both function to loop without starting them. And then `run_forever()` will run both of them. `run_until_complete` starts task at one and wait for its real end, not for `await`.

Comment: But that's strange for me. Why the first run_until_complete ends instantly, while still providing websockets functionality (I can connect from client and it processes requests)? How is it different than the for in on_message()?

Comment: I don't have full code to confirm that websocket still running. I would said that it ended work.

Comment: It does. I connected many times from client app. Btw. I'm using the following for websockets.
https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`run_until_complete(task)` starts task at once and waits for its real end, not for `await`. But your second task uses `while True` which never ends.

You should rather add task to loop using `create_task(task)` and start loop later with `run_forever()`.

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(app_server)
print('1')
asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(remote_data_retriever())
print('2')
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

And then both tasks will run in one loop and `await` will stop one task to start another task.

---

Example code which everyone can run

```
import asyncio

async def task_1():
    number = 0
    while True:
        number += 1
        print('task1', number)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def task_2():
    number = 0
    while True:
        number += 1
        print('task2', number)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.create_task(task_1())
        print('1')
        loop.create_task(task_2())
        print('2')
        loop.run_forever()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your exact suggestion doesn't work as create_task() throws exception (correctly) claiming app_server is not a coroutine. However, based on your proposed code, I've been able to get it to work like this:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    asyncio.ensure_future(app_server, loop=loop)
    print('1')
    loop.create_task(remote_data_retriever())
    print('2')
    loop.run_forever()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```